# Abstract in programming

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

The word abstract is when we talk about a queue class or any class. A class is abstract right? How's the word abstract used in programming. Somehing that is abstract? What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract in OO is used to indicate that the class cannot be instantiated directly and must be inherited from before instantiation. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29#Abstract_classes) explains this nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Abstract means that you are discussing an idea one or more levels away from any specific example that you can actually point to or create.

As far as classes are concerned, an abstract class is abstract because it can't be instantiated.  A specific class that can be instantiated is concrete, and it may be an example of a certain abstract class.

Similarly, if your data structures class discusses an 'abstract' data type such as a Queue, the teacher means Queue as 'a FIFO data structure'.  Slightly less absract is Java's AbstractQueue.  A concrete queue that you can "point to" (not in the sense of pointers and memory, but in the sense "THERE is a queue!") could be Java's LinkedBlockingQueue

```
`Abstract` ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...   `Concrete`
 a queue            AbstractQueue                LinkedBlockingQueue
 a group            an infinite group            positive integers
 a car         a Ford       1995 Ford Taurus     My 1995 Ford Taurus VIN# 3489230148230
```

Answer (score 1):

The term "abstract" can mean a whole bunch of different things, depending on the context.

The two most common uses of "abstract" pertain to object-oriented programming.  A method is called "abstract" (or, in C++-speak, "pure virtual") if the method does not have an implementation.  The purpose of an abstract method is to indicate that classes that inherit from the given class will all have a method with the given signature, but there is no reasonable default behavior for that method.  A common example is, in a class hierarchy of shapes, that the base class for shapes might have an abstract method that draws the shape on the screen.  There is no good default behavior for drawing "a shape" - what shape it it? - but any individual shape will have a concrete implementation of this function.

A related term is an "abstract class," which is a class that contains an abstract method.  Because the class contains this abstract method, you can't have a concrete object of that class type.  Otherwise, if you tried calling the abstract method, you'd find out that there was no implementation associated with it.

In an entire different context, the word "abstract" sometimes shows up in the term "abstract data type," which is a term used to describe an object supporting some set of mathematical operations without necessarily explaining how those operations are implemented.  For example, "stack," "queue," and "list" are all abstract data types, since they describe what behaviors are expected of a given type of object without giving implementation (e.g. dynamic array?  linked list?  hash table?)

The term "abstract" also comes up in "abstraction," which is some simplification of a complex system into something more managable.  For example, network routing is usually broken down into a different number of "layers," each of which are responsible for handling some part of the end-to-end communication.  Each layer is tasked with a specific job, and must take in input and produce output in a predetermined fashion.  This lets programmers work on one layer treat all the other layers as "black boxes" that magically get the job done, since provided that you give input to the layer in the right form or read the output of some layer in a specific manner, you don't need to worry about the details of how that layer works.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well a good example in OO is an Animal, you'd have an abstract class like so:

```
abstract class Animal
{
     public AnimalType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can't declare an animal outright, you must have a class that inherits from an animal, like a cat:

```
class Cat : Animal
{
       public Cat()
       {
             Type = AnimalType.Feline; 
       }
}
```

So this wouldn't work:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
```

But this would:

```
Animal a = new Cat();
```

So in essence, what you're saying, is this is a base class, you can't make one on it's own, you need more information, say a class that inherits from it. Kind of hard to explain, so hope the example helps!

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated and instead are inherited from by other classes, generally concrete ones. They usually contain code that is common to inheriting classes to minimize code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can mean a couple of things related to programming. But, for me, I think of it related to virtual methods, which may perform different tasks depending on the underlying object type. That would be in contrast to a method that always does the same, fixed set of operations.

In fact there are "abstract classes", where one or more methods are pure virtual, which means they are not implemented by that class. Such a class cannot be instantiated. Instead, you must derive a new class from it that implements the pure virtual methods, and then you can instantiate the second class.

Answer (score 0):

Abstraction is a way of building compound objects from simpler ones. A function for example can be seen a form of black box abstraction ..where the inner workings of the function are hidden from the user.

Data abstraction in general  is a methodology that enables programmers to isolate how a compound data object is used from the details of how it is constructed from more primitive data objects.